# Solving partial differential equation with DSolve does not give a result

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation:

$-(d^2/dx^2+d^2/dy^2)\psi+(x^2+y^2-2)\psi=0$

Here, is my code:

```
Eq = -(D[ψ[x, y], {x,2}] + D[ψ[x, y], {y,2}]) + (x^2 + y^2 - 2) ψ[x, y] == 0;

DSolve[Eq, ψ, {x, y}]
```

The output returns an unevaluated expression.

Why do I receive such a thing? The solution to the PDE is:

$\psi=\exp(-1/2(x^2+y^2))$

Comment: I think your equation should be expressed as `Eq = -(D[ψ[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[ψ[x, y], {y, 2}]) + (x^2 + y^2 - 2) ψ[x, y] == 0;`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But, the output is not sensible. Why do you think so? Can you explain it more?

Comment: @NoOne Another way of writing it would be `Eq = -(Derivative[2, 0][\[Psi]][x, y] + 
       Derivative[0, 2][\[Psi]][x, y]) + (x^2 + y^2 - 2) \[Psi][x, 
      y] == 0;`. But since that returns evaluated it means MMA couldn't solve it. Update the question with the correct syntax and ask instead how one can get MMA to solve this PDE.

Comment: @Pickett; Why do you put [0, 2] and [2, 0] in some places? I do not understand it.

Comment: After you correct the equation as suggested by m_goldberg, DSolve returns the input. Which means DSolve can't find analytical solution. Not every PDE has analytical solution. You can try numerical solution?

Comment: Ok, I validated your particular solution after an initial typo. Here is the code fyi: `eq = -(D[phi[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[phi[x, y], {y, 2}]) + (x^2 + y^2 - 2) phi[x, y] == 0;
eq /. phi -> (Exp[-1/2 (#1^2 + #2^2)] &)
Simplify[%]` gives `True` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tb7WH.png)  but as was said, this is just one particular solution. `DSolve` finds general solutions

Comment: This should not be closed as off-topic. It may be a simple mistake, but the question is asking WHAT the mistake is. The answer is also NOT easily found in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive the radial solution to your differential equation as follows:

```
Eq = -(D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[f[x, y], {y, 2}]) + (x^2 + y^2 - 2) f[x,y] == 0;
```

Assume that the solution is of the form `fr[r]` where `r^2 = x^2 + y^2`, and transform the `{x, y}` differential equation to the corresponding `r` differential equation.

```
Eqr = Eq /. f -> (fr[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2]] &) /. y^2 -> r^2 - x^2 // PowerExpand // Simplify

(* (-2 + r^2) fr[r] == Derivative[1][fr][r]/r + (fr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] *)
```

Solve the radial differential equation.

```
solfr = DSolve[Eqr, fr, {r}][[1]]

(*
  {fr -> Function[{r}, E^(-(r^2/2)) C[1]
                 + 1/2 E^(-(r^2/2)) C[2] ExpIntegralEi[r^2]]}
*)
```

Transform the radial solution `fr[r]` back to the corresponding `f[x, y]` solution.

```
solf = solfr /. {fr -> f, {r} -> {x, y}, r^2 -> x^2 + y^2}

(*
  {f -> Function[{x, y}, E^(-(1/2) (x^2 + y^2)) C[1]
                   + 1/2 E^(-(1/2) (x^2 + y^2)) C[2] ExpIntegralEi[x^2 + y^2]]}
*)
```

Verify that this solves the differential equation.

```
Eq /. solf // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: It is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The Mathematica code you posted does not correspond to the equation you wrote.  `D[f[x],x]` denotes/computes a single derivative.  The second derivative, `f''[x]`, should be written as `D[f[x],{x,2}]`.

Please read the documentation of [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/D.html).

The correct way to translate this equation into Mathematica code is

```
-(D[ψ[x, y], {x,2}] + D[ψ[x, y], {y,2}]) + (x^2 + y^2 - 2) ψ[x, y] == 0
```

Using `DSolve` on this equation returns unevaluated.  This mean that Mathematica can not solve this equation symbolically.

Note: The solution you quote is valid, but it is not general.  It is not the only solution this equation has.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the specific solution, which I said in the question, from the above code in some way?

Comment: @NoOne You'd have to explain in what way that particular solution is special, and use that criterion.  At this point we are getting into math (not Mathematica).  For example if you are looking for a rotationally symmetric solution (like the one you posted), you can use that criterion to rewrite the equation as a 1D one.