# DSolve gives no output

Tags: differential-equations

I have troubles finding a solution to a system of three coupled nonlinear ODEs. When I put it into Mathematica, I get back the input as an answer. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
DSolve[{D[f[x], x] == I*Sqrt[2]*g[x], 
D[g[x], x] == 2*Sqrt[2]*g[x]*h[x], 
D[h[x], x] == I*(Sqrt[2]/2)*f[x]*h[x]/g[x]}, {f, g, h}, x]
```

Thank you for any help

P.S: I know that the closed form solution exists, I'm just trying to find it myself using Mathematica. The solution should be $f(x)=-A\cos x$, $g(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}iA\sin x$, $h(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\cot x$, where $A$ is a const.

I can check that this is a true solution by direct inspection, but I want to know how to get it to start with.

Comment: duplicate question? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50758/solving-partial-differential-equation-with-dsolve-does-not-give-a-result

Comment: @m00nlight I don't think it's a duplicate since the question you linked is not about the *coupled* ODEs. There were questions similar to mine asked here (I checked) but none of them got the answer I'm afraid, apart form suggestions that there are no solutions in closed form

Comment: @GregVoit If you know that it exists, may be you know something about these solutions and, thus, can help Mma somehow? Such as, say, by transforming your equations using your knowledge. Think about it.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I already tried everything I could I'm afraid, before posting a question here. That's why I'd be grateful for any specific hints - everything I thought I could try I already tried

Comment: @GregVoit So can you give the closed form solution to the equation, which may be helpful ?

Comment: @m00nlight I added it now to the question

Comment: Well, fast and dirty (that is you should check each step) you may introduce `G[x]=Log[g[x]]; H[x]=Log[h[x]] `then `G'=2Sqrt[2]*Exp[H] `,  `H'=I*f*Exp[-G]/Sqrt[2] ` and `f'=I*Sqrt[2]*Exp[G] `. From here you easily get `H''=-1-2Sqrt[2]*H'*Exp[H] `. If I did not make a mistake, of course, check it.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I agree with your expressions, however, how to I go about the last second-order ODE for H? Mathematica doesn't give a closed form solution for that (I get error function in it)

Comment: Another solution is: h(x)=0, g(x)=C[1], f(x)= I*Sqrt(2)*C[1]*x+C[2].

Comment: Is it possible that Mathematica does not yield complex solutions in analytical form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that it exists, may be you know something about these solutions and, thus, can help Mma somehow? Such as, say, by transforming your equations using your knowledge.

You may operate as follows: you may introduce

`G[x]=Log[g[x]]; 
H[x]=Log[h[x]]`

then

`G'=2Sqrt[2]*Exp[H]`

`H'=I*f*Exp[-G]/Sqrt[2]`

and

`f'=I*Sqrt[2]*Exp[G]`

From here you easily get

`H''=-1-2Sqrt[2]*H'*Exp[H]`

Let us do all this using Mma. These are the equations:

```
eq1 = g'[x] == 2*Sqrt[2]*h[x]*g[x];
eq2 = h'[x] == (I*f[x]*h[x])/(Sqrt[2]*g[x]);
eq3 = f'[x] == I*Sqrt[2]*g[x];
```

Now, let us transform them as follows:

```
eq1A = eq1 /. {g -> (Exp[G[#]] &), h -> (Exp[H[#]] &)} // 
  Simplify[#, G[x] != 0] &
eq2A = eq2 /. {g -> (Exp[G[#]] &), h -> (Exp[H[#]] &)} // 
  Simplify[#, {G[x] != 0, H[x] != 0}] &
eq3A = eq3 /. {g -> (Exp[G[#]] &), h -> (Exp[H[#]] &)} // 
  Simplify[#, {G[x] != 0, H[x] != 0}] &
```

which gives

```
(*
2 Sqrt[2] E^H[x] == Derivative[1][G][x]

-I Sqrt[2] f[x] + 2 E^G[x] Derivative[1][H][x] == 0

Derivative[1][f][x] == I Sqrt[2] E^G[x]
*)
```

Then let us get the derivative of the both parts of eq2A:

```
eq2B = Map[D[#, x] &, eq2A]

(*  -I Sqrt[2] Derivative[1][f][x] + 
  2 E^G[x] Derivative[1][G][x] Derivative[1][H][x] + 
  2 E^G[x] (H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0  *)
```

Now let us eliminate from this system f' and G':

```
Eliminate[{eq3A, eq2B, eq1A}, {f'[x], G'[x]}] // 
 Simplify[#, {G[x] != 0, H[x] != 0}] &
```

I show the result as a picture, to see it better:

[image]

Now one can solve it:

```
     eq1 = H''[x] == -1 - 2 Sqrt[2]*H'[x]*Exp[H[x]]
   sol = DSolve[eq1, H[x], x]
```

returning

```
(* {{H[x] -> 
   1/2 (-x^2 - 2 x C[1] - 
      2 Log[2 Sqrt[
         2] (-C[2] + 
           E^(C[1]^2/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Erf[(x + C[1])/Sqrt[2]])])}}  *)
```

To get `h[x]` you return to the definition:

```
 Exp[H[x]] /. sol // FullSimplify


(*  {E^(-(1/2) x (x + 2 C[1]))/(
 Sqrt[2] (-2 C[2] + 
    E^(C[1]^2/2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Erf[(x + C[1])/Sqrt[2]]))}  *)
```

And, finally, let us solve it numerically and build a plot out of the solution with arbitrarily chosen initial conditions:

```
 sol2 = NDSolve[{H''[x] == -1 - 2 Sqrt[2]*H'[x]*Exp[H[x]], H[0] == 3, 
    H'[0] == 1}, H, {x, 0, 3}];
Plot[Log[H[x]] /. sol2, {x, 0, 3}]
```

giving

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: thank you, I think I can proceed from here now